# Using Netty with Scala

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, netty

I use Netty 4.0.0.CR3 in my Scala 2.10.1 application. This client side code

```
...
val b: Bootstrap = new Bootstrap
b.group(group).channel(classOf[NioSocketChannel]).handler(new QueryWebClientIntializer)
...
```

causes the compilation error

```
not found: value classOf
    b.group(group).channel(classOf[NioSocketChannel]).handler(new QueryWebClientIntializer)
```

This server side code

```
...
val b: ServerBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap
b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup).channel(classOf[NioServerSocketChannel]).childHandler(new QueryWebServerInitializer(server))
...
```

works perfectly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried `Predef.classOf`?

Comment: @Alexlv Strangely enough, it worked, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Predef.classOf[].
```

Thanks to @AlexIv